# Como crear un user para un profile en la API django

Tags: django, api

Tengo esto en este serializador:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
   shops = ShopListingField(read_only=False, required=False)
   publishers = PublisherListingField(read_only=False, required=False)
   profile_types = ProfileTypeListingField(read_only=False, required=False)
   cooperative_universes = CooperativeUniverseListingField(read_only=False, required=False)
   countries = CountryListingField(read_only=False, required=False)
   language = LanguageField(read_only=False, required=False, queryset=Language.objects.all())
   username = UserField(read_only=False, required=True, queryset=User.objects.all())
```

El `UserField` es:

```
class UserField(serializers.RelatedField):

  def to_representation(self, value):
      return value.username

  def to_internal_value(self, data):
      user_found = User.objects.filter(username=data)
      if user_found:
          raise serializers.ValidationError(u'%s (%s)' % (_(u'username already exists'), data))
      else:
          user = User.objects.create(username=data)
          return user
```

La idea es que en el data del POST, viene un username de un usario que tengo que crear en mi sistema, junto con su profile. Entonces me cree un profile serialicer y el username lo trato en el `to_internal_value` para que se cree y se devuelva. Esto creo que no está bien, pero no sé como hacerlo correctamente.

Supongo que tendría que crear un serializer para crear un User y luego hacer que se le pase al campo `username` del `ProfileSerializer`, pero no estoy seguro de como hacerlo.

Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: @Alfredo Paz - ¿Porque has dejado `to_internal_value`, `username` y `ProfileSerializer` sin formato codigo? Son elementos del codigo... También gracias - [¿Cómo dar las gracias a los usuarios que responden a mis preguntas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3415/por-qué-combaten-los-buenos-modales-en-so)

Comment: tienes razón @Juan Alvarez disculpa ya le he agregado formato

Comment: @AlfredoPaz - Has olvidado las gracias... y también tengo una edición rechazada por nada... en el futuro, tiene mas cuidado en las colas de revisión, por favor.